# HBase MapReduce with google.inject mismatch

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, guice, maven-shade-plugin, guice-servlet

I'm trying to do a map reduce against a HBase table using our in-house framework which makes use of Guice 4.0

It looks like yarn might be using version 3.0 and I'm getting a type mismatch.

`2016-03-25 08:19:45,784 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.multibindings.MultibindingsScanner$1.binder()Lcom/shaded/google/inject/Binder;
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.MultibindingsScanner$1.configure(MultibindingsScanner.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at my.packagename.client.KafkaModule.configure(KafkaModule.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at my.packagename.hbase_fix.CleanerMapper.setup(CleanerMapper.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)`

In the same piece of work I had a similar mismatch with fasterxml so used the `maven-shade-plugin` to successfully relocate but I've not been so successful with com.google.inject

`<relocations>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>com.fasterxml</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>com.shaded.fasterxml</shadedPattern>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com.fasterxml.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>org.apache.commons.lang</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.commons.lang</shadedPattern>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org.apache.commons.lang.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>com.google.inject.Binder</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>com.shaded.google.inject.Binder</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
    <pattern>com.google.inject.multibindings</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>com.shaded.google.inject.multibindings</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
</relocations>`

Any suggestions on how to get round type mismatch in MapReduce jobs specifically with google.inject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy solution to this. In the end it came down to forcing the mapreduce classpath to have a copy of guice4 come first so the code would run.

Not ideal but the only solution found